# hMailer PHPWebMail not working

Tags: php, iis-8, plesk, hmail-server

I get the following error

> Failed to create COM object `hMailServer.Application': Access is
>   denied.
>
> This problem is often caused by DCOM permissions not being set.

I tried almost all the suggestions about enabling php dcoms and giving dcom permission. In fact, I have given "Everyone" permissions.

My server is running on Windows IIS 8, with Parallels Plesk installed. 
PHP 5.5, hMailserver 5.x, Mod Security Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

```
;com.allow_dcom = true
```

Set in your PHP.INI?

Answer (score 0):

Find the line 
; extension=php_com_dotnet

and remove ; and save your php.ini file and restart Apache2, now the hMailServer COM
Error is gone.